# Where we can get older versions of VSCode (like 1.25) in ZIP format?

Tags: visual-studio-code, version

First of all, I have to make clear that I need the zip version because I will use it on Win 64 in the business and there we have no admin privileges on notebook.

I looked out over web but I wasn't able to find where I can get the VSCode v1.25(.1). I only found .EXE versions or source code archive.

Why I need this? VSCode 1.26 and greater (and many others electron based applications) are very slow in Win 64. Thank God I use Linux at home! Please, see this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/issues/4609

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after report it as [an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/60933) on github vscode repository, somebody gave me the provisory link and previous archives (zip) versions will be put available asap issue come to be solved.

[Obsolete!] VSCode 1.25.1 archive (zip) Win64 link: https://vscode-update.azurewebsites.net/1.25.1/win32-x64-archive/stable

Update 2023:
(by github user gregvanl).

> Download page https://code.visualstudio.com/download now has a link
> **"Get previous versions"**, which points to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_previous-release-versions.
> The URLs to each download are provided there.

Comment: says `Cannot GET /1.25.1/win32-x64-archive/stable`

Answer (score 5):

Go to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_previous-release-versions.

The URLs to each download are provided there.

Replace `{version}` you desire in the download URL string

[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 2):

The current accepted answer from **sdlins** is no longer correct as links are broken. Answer from **dhgoratela** is correct. Repeating here for clarity and CnP convenience.

Links of the form `https://update.code.visualstudio.com/{version}/win32-x64-archive/stable` will download a zip. Note that for major versions like 1.75, you need to use 1.75.0 as the version number.

Examples:

https://update.code.visualstudio.com/1.76.2/win32-x64-archive/stable (win zip)
https://update.code.visualstudio.com/1.76.2/linux-x64/stable (linux tar)
https://update.code.visualstudio.com/1.76.2/darwin-arm64/stable (mac arm)

The source for these links can be found at https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/, although the link for a windows ZIP file must be manually constructed, since download url's with `win32-x64-archive` aren't posted on these pages.